# Complex analysis graphing an ellipse.

Tags: complex-analysis

Give a geometric argument that $|z-4i|+|z+4i|=10$.
My attempt: $|z-4i|$ represents the distance from an arbitrary point to the coordinate $(0,4i)$ while $|z+4i|$ is the distance from an arbitrary point to the coordinate $(0,-4i)$.
Then stuck; I don't know how this relates to an ellipse...Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the definition of an ellipse, then you'll see ...

Comment: Something's missing here that I guess you forgot to mention. $|z-4i|+|z+4i|$ is not equal to $10$ when, e.g. $z=0$. I guess you meant, "how do I draw the set of points with $|z-4i|+|z+4i| = 10$?"

Answer (score 2):

An ellipse is a set of points such that the sum of the distances from each point in the set to a pair of fixed points is a constant.

Here is a derivation of the equation of an ellipse from this definition:

Imagine you have tacks at the points $(-c,0$ and $(c,0)$, which hold each end of a string of length $2 a$.  We draw an ellipse by holding a pen taut against the string.  The sum of the distances to a point on the ellipse from each of the tack points is

$$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2} + \sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2} = 2 a$$

The trick is to manage the algebra so that the derivation is readable.  First, square both sides to get

$$(x-c)^2 + (x+c)^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2+2 c x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2-2 c x} = 4 a^2$$

This simplifies a little to

$$x^2+y^2+c^2+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+c^2)^2-4 c^2 x^2} = 2 a^2$$

Now we need to rid ourselves of this remaining square root by isolating it:

$$\begin{align}(x^2+y^2+c^2)^2-4 c^2 x^2 &= [2 a^2 - (x^2+y^2+c^2)]^2\\ &= 4 a^4 - 4 a^2 (x^2+y^2+c^2) + (x^2+y^2+c^2)^2 \end{align}$$

We have some fortuitous cancellation which leaves us with a quadratic.  Rearrange to get

$$(a^2-c^2) x^2 + a^2 y^2 = a^2 (a^2-c^2)$$

or, in standard form:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2-c^2} = 1$$

Note that, for an ellipse, $a>c$.  We interpret $a$ to be the semimajor axis, $c$ to be the focal length, and $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$ is the semiminor axis.